# When saving category with other language get invalid key url

Tags: magento2, product, category, language, url-key

I am using Magento version 2.2.3 . When I want to save new category in other language from English I get invalid URL key error. This is my log in var folder of Magento project

> Invalid URL key {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(code: 0): Invalid URL key at E:\wamp64\www\magento\vendor\magento\module-catalog-url-rewrite\Observer\CategoryUrlPathAutogeneratorObserver.php:61)"} []

How to solve it and with what extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In magento2 sometimes it doesn't work with the Unicode characters, especially in the URL-rewrite. so you can check the below-mentioned module and let us know if that will helped you.

https://github.com/studioraz/magento2-unicode-url

Comment: hello. thanks for your response. I will check it now

Comment: I am very grateful to you. Thanks for your guidance. this worked well

Comment: Happy to help :)